# How to calculate the speed of slide screen? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have create image slideshow.By create group of image group.Like this image:

[image]

Now I can do slide using the mouse to move.The example code like this.

```
local sScrolling
local sInitialMouseX, sInitialMouseY
local sInitialHScroll, sInitialVScroll

on mouseDown
   ## Allow the group to scroll
   put true into sScrolling

   ## Record the initial touch position
   put item 1 of the mouseLoc into sInitialMouseX
   put item 2 of the mouseLoc into sInitialMouseY

   ## Record the initial hScroll and vScroll
   put the vScroll of me into sInitialVScroll
   put the hScroll of me into sInitialHScroll
end mouseDown

on mouseMove mouseX, mouseY
   ## If the screen is being touched then
   if sScrolling then      
      ## Calculate how far the touch has moved since it started
      put mouseY - sInitialMouseY into tVChange
      put mouseX- sInitialMouseX into tHChange

      ## Reset the hScroll and vScroll to follow the touch
      lock screen
      --      set the vScroll of me to sInitialVScroll - tVChange
      set the hScroll of me to sInitialHScroll - tHChange
      unlock screen
      put the hScroll of me && tHChange into fld "labS"
   end if
end mouseMove

on mouseRelease
   mouseUp
end mouseRelease

on mouseUp
   put false into sScrolling
end mouseUp
```

I want a damping and has Snap pictures like slideshow on various App in IOS.

Guide for me please or preview code.

Comment: What does "want a damping and has Snap pictures" mean exactly? I think you want some kind of visual effect. Are you making an app for iOS or Android? Then you could have a look at the scrollerDidScroll, scrollerBeginDrag and scrollerEndDrag messages. The scrollerDidScroll message would allow you to scroll while the scrollerEndDrag message would tell you that it is time to decide whether or not to slide till the end and which effect to apply.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example will give you some ideas on damping (I'm assuming you mean acceleration / deceleration).  I've used these simple easeIn / easeOut formulae in games and apps where I've used my own scrollers rather than native scrollers.

(An example can be seen in the animations in the 'Dog Tales' app ...
http://dogtales.splash21.com/chapter1-2.php )

Create a new stack and add a graphic named "Ball".  Put the following code into the card...

```
command moveBall
   local tSpeed
   set the left of graphic "Ball" to 0
   repeat with tIndex = 1 to 100
      put 10 * easeOut(100, tIndex) into tSpeed
      set the left of graphic "Ball" to the left of graphic "Ball" + tSpeed
      wait for 2 millisecs
   end repeat
end moveBall


function easeIn pMax, pVal, pPow
   local tResult
   if pPow is not a number then put 1.25 into pPow
   put (pVal / pMax) ^ pPow into tResult
   if tResult > 1 then
      return 1
   else if tResult < 0 then
      return 0
   else
      return tResult
   end if
end easeIn


function easeOut pMax, pVal, pPow
   local tResult
   if pPow is not a number then put 1.25 into pPow
   put 1 - (pVal / pMax) ^ pPow into tResult
   if tResult > 1 then
      return 1
   else if tResult < 0 then
      return 0
   else
      return tResult
   end if
end easeOut
```

Comment: I understand that you told me but I don't understand that how I should evaluate the values of speed? Otherwise, can you do the example for me about this process? Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code raises a few questions. E.g. what exactly are you scrolling. Your picture isn't too enlightening either. My guess is that you want to decide whether to continue scrolling after mouseUp or to set the hscroll back to its original value. Apparently, you need some thresholds and I don't know the values of the thresholds, so you have to figure that out yourself for now.

```
on mouseUp
   put false into sScrolling
   if (sInitialMouseX - sInitialHScroll) > myThreshold then
     set the hScroll of me to myScrollTillTheEnd
   else
      set the hScroll of me to sInitialHScroll 
   end if
end mouseUp
```

If you decide that the group should flip to the other side of and only if the user moves the finger by more than 50 pixels, then 50 is a threshold value and you could replace myThreshold with 50.

Comment: Threshold = ธรณีประตู. (Maybe not exactly the correct translation. I mean something like a limit, a border value. E.g. if you decide that the group should flip to the other side of and only if the user moves the finger by more than 50 pixels, then 50 is a threshold value and you could replace myThreshold with 50.